# Currency units are misleading for jobs in less-common dollar countries

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, stack-overflow-jobs, internationalization

I am in Singapore.  If I search for jobs making at least 100,000 USD per year, here is one of the results:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/159086/search-engineer-data-scientist-discovery-redmart

It shows the salary range as "$72k - 120k".  So it must be in USD, because if those numbers were in Singapore Dollars (which is the currency the job pays in), they wouldn't match the search criteria.

The site is doing employers in dollar countries outside the US a large disservice, because anyone would read a posting for a Singapore job and assume it shows Singapore dollars.  So this job which actually pays $99k to $165k in Singapore is listed as $72k - 120k, which will discourage people from applying.

It's needlessly confusing.  Please just write "US$72k - 120k" or "72k - 120k USD" explicitly for jobs not physically located in the US but whose displayed currency is US dollars.

Comment: "It must be in USD".  You can't draw that conclusion, only that the database thinks that it is.  The person entering the job psting might have gotten confused and typed an SGD salary range into a USD input field.

Comment: @BenVoigt: That's true.  If my proposal is enacted, the company  posting the job would likely spot the error, though, because as soon as they viewed their own posting they'd realize the salary currency was not what they thought it was.

Comment: Since you're already using SI prefixes, why not go wholly metric and use kiloEuro's as the native currency? :P

Answer (score 32):

**A dollar sign alone ("$") seems to always represent "USD"**.

- When the salary is in Singapore Dollar, an ISO 4217 code is used: "SGD 60k - 90k" (see [**this job offer**](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/157654/software-engineer-in-machine-learning-leadiq) as an example).
- [**Another example**](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/180009/game-programmer-dead-by-daylight-behaviour-interactive?so=i&pg=1&offset=-1&l=canada&u=Km&d=20) with a salary in Canadian Dollar using the symbol "C$".
- And [**another example**](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/197122/remote-senior-full-stack-rails-developer-year-old-startup?so=i&pg=1&offset=7&l=Australia&u=Km&d=20) which uses "A$" to represent Australian Dollar.

---

**I am in favor of this feature request** anyway. ISO 4217 codes will always be clearer than "$" or "C$", considering [**so many countries**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dollar#Economies_that_use_a_dollar) use different dollars, [**a few others**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peso#Countries_that_use_pesos) use pesos which are also represented by a dollar sign (in most cases). And there are [**even**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicaraguan_c%C3%B3rdoba) [**more**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tongan_pa%CA%BBanga) currencies that use the dollar sign...

Any other representation is confusing on some level. As an example, the "C$" sign which is used to differentiate Canadian Dollars from other dollars, also happens to be the official sign for the [**Nicaraguan córdoba**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicaraguan_c%C3%B3rdoba). We should simply use "CAD" instead!

## Let's use [ISO 4217](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217#Active_codes)!

Comment: A potential issue with this is that people unfamiliar with ISO currency codes may not realize what the \*\*\*\* a "USD" (or "CAD" or "SGD" or whatever) even is. Even if they can eventually figure it out after staring at the acronym for a while, it's still an unnecessary mental hurdle. A useful compromise notation might be something like "$60k - 95k SGD", preferably with the "SGD" marked up as an `<abbr>`eviation for "Singapore Dollars" in the HTML. Or even "$60k - 95k SGD (approx. $44k - 69k USD)" for easier comparison between currencies.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: That's even worse for someone who doesn't know the ISO currency codes, because they'll see the dollar sign and assume they know what it means.  Just use the mouseover text on the ISO currency format.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: People who live in dollar countries outside the US know their own currency code.  They're used to it.  Sometimes they have their own local code too, but those are ambiguous so we probably shouldn't bother with them (e.g. RM for MYR, S$ for SGD).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Even people in the US who don't ever see other ISO currency codes are unlikely to be confused by USD.  It shows up enough on the internet, and even some domestic sales tags, that it would be hard to not know what it means.  They might not know what a "CAD" is, but that probably means they're not looking to move to Canada any time soon and thus are unlikely to see that code on a job search.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen:  That is easily addressed by the sidebar having a clickable "currencies explained" or some such which explains ISO 4217, maybe linked directly to the Wikipedia article.